# What is the best way to share data between two maven plugins that will be executed sequentially and individually

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have two maven plugins that will be executed one after another. When first plugin is executed it process some data and I want to store some of those data temporally so that the second plugin can use those data in it's execution.

I tried to use log files for this purpose but it feel like more works. Is there any standard better way like a framework or library to share those data between maven plugins ?

P.S

Two plugin will be executed in the same directory. First plugin is processing some pom files and Second plugin will feed information on to a external rest service. Those two plugins can be executed individually(i.e Second plugin doesn't depend on the execution of first plugin). However second plugin will feed information generated by first plugin if those information are present.

Comment: Can you explain more detail what those plugins do? Why do you need to share between plugins? An example would be great..

Comment: @khmarbaise please see my updated question. Hope the question is clear now. Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: I would make a single plugin of it...and have different goals which will solve the issue...